# remap kinesis keyboard with modifier keys

Tags: macos, mac, remapping, kinesis-advantage

I just purchased a kinesis advantage and would like to remap the "delete" key (delete character right of cursor) to `[shift] [Back Space]` using `[prgrm] [f12 Remap]`. This failed as [Shift] is now performing the delete functionality. Is there a way to use modifiers when doing a remap?

As I'm using the keyboard on mac os x(10.9.5), I'm also interested to know whether I can reach a similar effect by modifying mac mappings.

Answer (score 2):

Remapping only works for single key actions, you cannot map key combinations using this feature. To map a key combination to a single key, you need to use the macro feature.

In this case, you would do:

1. Press <kbd>Progrm</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>Progrm</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

Comment: I was struggling to remap a key that was only accessible via shift as well, and this helped me a lot. I'd forgotten about macros..